# Adding button in toolbar for intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I am writing a Plugin for intelliJ IDEA and I have been trying to add a button in the main toolbar, besides the run button:

[image]

I have been looking for guides to help me do it, but I haven't found any. It has to be possible, this is just my first plugin and I lack the necessary experience. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. You have to create an action (descendant of AnAction) and put it in **Actions** tag within your plugin.xml:

```
    <actions>
      <action id="your.action.id" class="your.Action"
            text="Some label" description="Action description" icon="AllIcons.General.AddJdk">
        <add-to-group group-id="ToolbarRunGroup" anchor="first" />
      </action>
    </actions>
```

The "add-to-group" tag will tell IDEA to put it together with other execution related buttons.

Comment: This appears to break in the new IntelliJ UI